# The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist

Tags: java, maven

Al hacer mvn clean ó mvn install desde el jboss developer me muestra el siguiente error. He revisado el siguiente enlace, pero no me ayuda o dice mucho a configurar desde eclipse: [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192761/spring-maven-clean-error-the-requested-profile-pom-xml-could-not-be-activate)

El error que me muestra en consola es el siguiente:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building simul 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ simul ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\workspace_alterno\simul\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.375 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-28T17:03:22-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project simul: Failed to clean project: 
Failed to delete D:\workspace_alterno\simul\target\simul.war -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Uso java jdk8, mi java_home apunta a mi jdk8, y mi pom.xml también tiene:

```
<properties>
    <spring-framework.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

También he intentado ejecutarlo mediante la terminal y error persiste, por favor si alguien tiene la solución mencionarla bien detallado, gracias!

Comment: agrega el logger del debug ejecuta mvn install -X. si tienes mas de una versión de java instalada ejecuta desde cmd java -version para comprobar cual es la versión esta tomando en cuenta.

Comment: @Polo gracias por comentar, ejecutando "mvn install" desde la terminal me muestra el mismo error, y con "java -version" y "javac -version" apunta bien a mi jdk 1.8.0_51

Answer (score 1):

La solución fue reiniciar el jbossDeveloper, este IDE tiene algunos bugs que no refrescan bien al momento de desarrollar aplicaciones

Answer (score 0):

otra posible solución es esta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192761/spring-maven-clean-error-the-requested-profile-pom-xml-could-not-be-activate/48051852 donde el problema es que hay un conflicto con las versiones de java que tienes en el pom.xml y la que tienes en el runtime, yo tenia en el runtime java 11 y en el pom.xml java 8, cambié el runtime a java 8 y solucionó el problema.

Answer (score -1):

Actualiza la versión del STS a la número 4.10
evitando usar versiones anteriores a la 4
Ej. Usar la versión 3.9.8 te genera ese error de que el pom.xml no existe!